# Android Oreo (26) remove Rule from RelativeLayout.Params causes ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-8.0-oreo

I just tried to launch my App with the new Android Oreo system image on a virtual Android Device.
However, the app immediately crashes at this line:
`params1.removeRule(params1.getRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF));`

The complete code segment looks like this:

```
// Center the c's by removing the layout relation with the 'inna'  
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)c1.getLayoutParams());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)c2.getLayoutParams());

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    params1.removeRule(params1.getRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF)); 
    params2.removeRule(params2.getRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF));
} else {
    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, 0);
    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_START, 0);
    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.START_OF, 0);
    params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 0);
    params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_END, 0);
    params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF, 0);
}
```

The stack trace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=22; index=2131296620
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.java:1453)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.java:1475)
        at my.super.app.screens.startUp.LoginScreen.onWindowFocusChanged(LoginScreen.java:160)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowFocusChanged(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:123)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onWindowFocusChanged(DecorView.java:1539)
        at android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:11974)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:1387)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3854)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

So, until SDK Version 26 this code worked just fine.
Any ideas?